# How to install E3D Volcano to CR-10 mini?

Tags: creality-ender-3, hotend, creality-cr-10, e3d

I have E3D Volcano and want to upgrade my CR-10 mini.

Found instructions how to change E3D Hotend for CR-10, but can't find any with CR-10 mini. Could I use same instruction that was made for CR-10?

Or better upgrade my Ender V2 with that E3D Volcano Hotend?

Comment: One question per question please. The latter question is opinion based though.

Comment: Maybe someone will answer that can use CR-10 instruction for CR-10 mini or someone will say that better is to upgrade Ender V2 if this option is available for me.

Comment: The word "better" is just very subjective. If you ask if it would be more straightforward (easier, simpler) it will be less about opinions. And still this is separate question :)

Comment: Also, the volcano is an all-metal hotend. That is not always an "upgrade" for all machines, it is a different tradeoff: lined hotends are easier to use for lower temperatures, all-metal hotends reach higher temperatures at the cost of ease of use.

Comment: Bought E3D Volcano, so I can use it for Nylon Carbon printing. OEM hotend doesn’t allow that high temperature which is needed to melt Nylon Carbon